# SSRS Histogram with bell curve or normal curve

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, sqlreportingservice

I'm trying to create a histogram chart with bell curve.

I found this link in creating histogram chart with SSRS.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2383/creating-a-reporting-services-histogram-chart-for-statistical-distribution-analysis/

but I can't add a bell curve within this chart. Anyone has tried adding a bell curve within the histogram chart?

SSRS 2008 or higher.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you saying you want to chart a dataset then you want to add another series that shows a bell curve? You can just have a combination bar and line chart but you'll need to provide the data for the line. Is the bell curve trying to fit the bars? There's nothing that does that natively in SSRS. You need to generate that dataset yourself

Comment: Hi, I see, but are there any links that I can make a query to form a histogram ready data? thanks!

Comment: Can you not just define your grouping in your dataset query and then return a simple dataset with your categories and two values per category to plot on a regular chart - one for column height and the other for your bell curve?

Comment: If the previous comments don't help, I suggest you post a sample of your data and your expected output.